# How can I connect a adminer docker container with a mariadb docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb, adminer

I was trying to create a PHP development environment with PHP, MariaDB, and a tutorial suggested to use Adminer for database management. So I generate my `docker-compose.yml` file like this:

```yaml
version : '3.1'

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html/
  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - ./mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    environment:
      ADMINER_DEFAULT_SERVER: db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

But when I set the volumes for MariaDB, I got an error in the Adminer login page. When I don't set them it seems to work well.

[image]

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: SQLSTATE [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve.

Answer (score 2):

```yaml
version : '3.1'

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html/
  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    volumes:
      - ./mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    environment:
      ADMINER_DEFAULT_SERVER: db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    links:
        - php
        - db
```

Comment: This is the answer I needed, but its a bit weak in describing what was missing.  Suggestion: You can use a `#` to make comments within the docker-compose file `links:       # Add links feature to correct the Adminer login problem.`    Additionally, I don't believe the `links: - php` is required, just the `links: - db`